# Have you seen Jane this morning? (meaning: this morning)

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect, time-reference

I have a question about the present perfect.

> A: Have you seen Jane this morning? (said in the morning)
>
> B: Yes, I have. I saw her an hour ago.

Here, does "this morning" mean "from the early morning until the present when speaker A was talking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The baby cries this morning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202490/the-baby-cries-this-morning)

Comment: No, thanks. It does not.

Comment: Don't look at the question but at the answer with the most votes and explain why it doesn't help you.

Comment: I'm asking about the specific meaning of "this meaning" in my sentence. That thread does not address this question at all.

Comment: `"Bob has worked at Fwacbar Company" means he worked there in the past, but does not indicate that he is working there now.` If speaker A is speaking "now" in the morning then why should "this morning" have any other meaning different from the one stated? "This morning" will include any time before the question was posed.

Comment: I am asking about the meaning of "this morning", but you keep asking me whether that irrelevant thread answers my question. You also explained the present perfect, which I'm not asking about. What is the matter with you? Yes, to me, "this morning" can be a question, even though it's obvious to you. So, you're much smarter than me!!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "this morning" means any time from very early morning to the moment of saying it (the present).
In your expression B, you have contracted "Yes, I have." to "Yes, I've". That contraction can't be made unless the auxiliary verb "have" is followed explicitly by a main verb, as in "Yes, I've seen her.".